# Slow network speed rtl8723 de

Tags: networking

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop alongside Windows, had problems getting wireless connection up and going, noticed speeds capped @ 40 Kb/s, normally that is not the case for my network because when I was wired I had 100+Kb/s and on other devices I could get over 100Kb/s, since I used a LAN cable to get updates and such. 
I ran `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and it returned

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de
```

Can anybody help me?

the `iwconfig` outputs

```
         Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: DC:45:17:25:B1:D9   
         Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
         Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
         Power Management:off
         Link Quality=97/100  Signal level=-20 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
         Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
         Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

The channels with least traffic is 1-4 and the ones with most traffic are 9-13

Comment: Connect to your wireless network, edit your question, and show me `iwconfig`.

Comment: the output is ```wlo1      IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"Los Valladares"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: DC:45:17:25:B1:D9   
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=49/100  Signal level=-63 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Placing data like that into comments makes it horrible to read. Please, in the future, edit your question, paste the data, select that text, and click the {} icon to format it and make it human readable. Since you've got a laptop, please move closer to your wireless router, and show me iwconfig again. I'm interested to see what happens to " Link Quality=49/100 Signal level=-63 dBm", and your download speed. What channel is your router set to? On your smart phone, install one of the many "Wifi Analyzer" apps, and read which channels have the most traffic, and which have the least.

Comment: You did it again...

Comment: I know... I did not understood, but I edited the original post so it shows that info and also the channels you requested

Comment: What channel is your router set to? Auto, or something else?

Comment: At the moment it shows that I am in Channel eleven... which has the most traffic overall

Comment: Yes, change it to channel 1 for now. You can try "auto" at a later time, if you wish. Retry wireless from your original location, and lets see `iwconfig` again, and your speed tests. Report back.

Comment: status please...